# How to loop across a growing java List

Tags: java, android

I have a java list of URLs. I wish to call a function for each URL in the list. And this function adds URL to the list.
Is it possible to loop over all the URLs including newly added URLs in the list?

```
for(String links: urls) {
    ar = getNews(links);
}
```

inside `getNews()` there is:

```
urls.add(json.optString("next"));
```

I did this successfully using recursion. By calling:

```
getNews(json.optString("next"));
```

inside `getNews()`

Comment: recursion works. Or, you can use the indexed loop (`for i = 0; ...`), since it allows concurrent modification, and checks for the exit condition at every iteration

Comment: can you also post getNews function code here i just want to know what is the use of getNews function here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular `for` loop and change the condition each iteration

```
int size = 1;
for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i) {
    ar = getNews(urls.get(i));
    size = urls.size();
}
```

Comment: Iti mght be clearer if you updated URLs inside the loop.

Comment: @AndyTurner true, but I based it on the OP code, maybe there is more functionality in `getNews()`

Comment: getNews() method is meant to fetch JSON object from a link and adds a string of tag "title" to an array and returns it.. also fetches pagination and adds it to url list. so URL can't be updated from inside loop directly.. that's why i am looping the function over the list

Answer (score 2):

Use a Queue instead of a list:

```
Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<>();
q.add(initial urls);
while (!q.isEmpty()) {
  String url = q.pop();
  q.addAll(readNews(url));
}
```

I am assuming that this code lives outside the `readNews` method, i.e. there is no recursion here.

Also, since I assume this is some sort of crawler, you might want to keep track of URLs you visited previously, to avoid visiting them again:

```
Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<>();
Set<String> visited = new LinkedHashSet<>();
q.add(initial urls);
while (!q.isEmpty()) {
  String url = q.pop();
  if (visited.add(url)) {
    q.addAll(readNews(url));
  }
}
```